# How do I get back to Ragefire Chasm from the spirit healer?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I died in ragefire chasm and since i was the healer and we are near the beginning i decided to release spirit. Big mistake, i can not find how to get back in. The last instance i played it was 3 seconds away from the graveyard. In this once i dont see it. I walked all the way to my body and was standing on the grave marker yet i was not able to get back in and play.

Where is the instance from the graveyard? Is is it north? southwest? etc i cant find it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This instance is actually inside Orgrimmar itself.  So, you want to head back into Orgrimmar, past the Valley of Strength, into The Drag and turn left down a tunnel into The Cleft of Shadow, down a ramp and left again and you should see it.

On this map http://www.wowpedia.org/File:WorldMap-Orgrimmar.jpg The entrance to the Cleft of Shadow is about where the T is in The Drag.

Good Luck :)